# Как передать данные из SQL запроса через Intent в email-клиент

Tags: android, sql, email, android-intent

Нужна помощь. Создаю приложение-смету, данные получаю из базы SQLite . Пытаюсь сделать отправку сметы по email . Можно ли отправить данные в цикле через Intent в email-клиент, или же это делается по другому?
Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "отправить данные в цикле через Intent в email-клиент"? Какую задачу вы хотите решить таким образом? Вообще такое не должно сработать. Вам, наверное, надо скорее, собрать строку, содержащую HTML и его передавать через Intent в почтовый клиент. Ну и/или файл вложением передавать.

Comment: В приложении отображаются данные из базы данных через Recyclerview. Мне надо передать эти данные в email-клиент. Файл вложением не хотелось бы. А как собрать строку, содержащую HTML?

Comment: Собрать HTML можно по разному. Хотя бы и просто в цикле строки складывать. Какой вам формат нужен - неизвестно, засим что-то конкретное подсказать сложно. Попробуйте <table> тэг использовать, наверное он вам и нужен.

Comment: Я, как Вы и предложили, буду использовать <table>. А как его запихнуть в String?

Comment: Ну... Просто запихиваете в строку и всё... Типа [так](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp): `String htmlString = "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>"`

Comment: А с sql запросом и while это будет работать?

Comment: Конечно, это же просто строка. Перед циклом добавьте в строку начальный тэг таблицы и тэги заголовка. В каждой итерации цикла добавляйте в строку новые тэги строки таблицы. После цикла - закройте тэг таблицы

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Буду пробовать.